# When do we need to use 'leastNormalMagnitude', 'leastNonzeroMagnitude'?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am developing a collection view, In some cases, to avoid runtime exceptions, I need to return my collection view size to a least minimum size. So that the view takes a minimum space which is too small to view.

Here is the code snippet I tried but I am getting the error:

> Ambiguous use of 'leastNonzeroMagnitude'

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, estimatedItemSize section: Int) -> CGSize {
   return .init(width: .leastNormalMagnitude, height: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)
}
```

But if I return `.init(width: 0.0, height: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)` there is no error.

I found a similar question [What is the difference between leastNormalMagnitude, leastNonZeroMagnitude and automaticDimention in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681070/what-is-the-difference-between-leastnormalmagnitude-leastnonzeromagnitude-and-a).
But there is no answer to this question.

Comment: You seem to be asking about how to fix a compiler error, but the title asks "when do we need to use..." instead. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation about [leastNonzeroMagnitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/leastnonzeromagnitude)

> This value compares less than or equal to all positive numbers, but greater than zero. If the type supports subnormal values, leastNonzeroMagnitude is smaller than leastNormalMagnitude; otherwise they are equal.

So simply, leastNonzeroMagnitude <= leastNormalMagnitude and in this scenario, it will make no difference.

---

Both `leastNonzeroMagnitude` and `leastNormalMagnitude` have static variables that return a Double | CGFloat | Float. The CGSize initial function cannot determine which value it may be from the above types. That's why the error appears. You can click the error and check the `Quick Help` menu on the right hand side of Xcode's navigation.

> Ambiguous use of 'leastNonzeroMagnitude'

[image]

To fix it, you just need to make `leastNormalMagnitude` and `leastNonzeroMagnitude` conform to the correct type before returning `CGSize`

```swift
let width: Double = .leastNormalMagnitude
let height: Double = .leastNonzeroMagnitude
return .init(width: width, height: height)
```